# Woocommerce rebuild sales report

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

We had one of our devs looking into optimizing our site as we are constantly battling slow queries. In their review they removed empty postmeta. They ran the following SQL

```
DELETE FROM wp_postmeta WHERE `meta_value` = '';
```

Report was around 180,000 records were removed. Everything seemed fine upon our review of the site and reports after this was executed.

They also added the following in our theme's functions file.

```
function delete_useless_post_meta() { 
global $wpdb; 
$table = $wpdb->prefix.'postmeta'; 
$wpdb->delete ($table, array('meta_key' => '_edit_last')); 
$wpdb->delete ($table, array('meta_key' => '_edit_lock')); 
$wpdb->delete ($table, array('meta_key' => '_wp_old_slug')); } 
add_action('wp_logout','delete_useless_post_meta');
```

Again things seemed fine.

BUT this morning when I logged in as usual to look at overnight sales I found that our reports are reporting almost nothing and started to freak out.

So my question is: is there a way that the WooCommerce sales reports can be rebuilt?

We have an issue where our database has been written a lot since we last know the reports were good and do not know how to restore the table to restore the reports.

Comment: This is probably hard or impossible to answer without an understanding of the queries that the report runs. Are these default reports in WooCommerce? I wonder if you could do some debugging here to see what records they need? Are you of the view that the `postmeta` data is used in the report?

Comment: I just ran a test of manually resaving a few orders. They then appeared in the reports again. So it appears that you can regenerate the postmeta that is missing by doing this. Unfortunately we have about 13,000 orders now to process. I feel there may be a little scripting on the way through the API. If that works I will update my question.

Comment: Can the report be made to run without these meta tables? Again, are these default reports in WooCommerce, or are they custom?

Comment: These are the default reports. It doesn't appear that they can be as they became erroneous once the postmeta was cleaned.